# Unable to find template error in Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony

When I upgraded the system running Symfony3.0 to version 3.4, the following error occured.
I've tried `php bin/console debug:router` `php bin/console debug:twig` , but the routing doesn't seem to be a problem.
What else should I consider?

**Error Code**

```
Unable to find template "@AhiSpAdmin/hq/analytics/shop.html.twig" (looked into: /home/Symfony/src/AppBundle/Resources/views).
```

**Code**
Controller.php

```php
/**
 * @Route("/hq/analytics")
 */
class AnalyticsController extends BaseAnalyticsController
{

    protected $staffRoute = "ahi_sp_admin_hq_analytics_staff";
    protected $articleRoute = "ahi_sp_admin_hq_analytics_article";

    /**
     * @Route("/shop/", defaults={"_format"="html"}, requirements={"_format"="html|csv"})
     * @Method("GET")
     *  
     * @Template()
     */
    public function shopAction(Request $request)
    {
        // Add Form
        $searchForm = $this->createForm(ShopMetricsSearchType::class, null, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('ahi_sp_admin_hq_analytics_shop'),
        ));
    }
```

routing.yml

```yaml
ahi_sp_admin:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /admin/
    schemes:  ["%secure_scheme%"]
```

config.yml

```yaml
framework:
    templating:
        engies: ['twig']
```

index.html.twig

```html
<a href="{{ path('ahi_sp_admin_shop_analytics_article', {
}) }}">
```

**Version**
Symfony 3.4.47
PHP 7.3

Comment: `@Template` is part of the SensioExtraBundle.   Around the time that 3.4+ was released there was a change to specification for template naming.  
See https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/issues/538 You can get around this by specifying the path to the template as a param in the `@Template` annotation or rename your templates.

Comment: @gview Thank you very much. Thanks to you, I was able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by specifying twig for `@Template`. Thanks to gview.

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/shop/", defaults={"_format"="html"}, requirements={"_format"="html|csv"})
     * @Method("GET")
     *  
     * @Template("AppBundle:Hq/Analytics:shop.html.twig")
     */
```

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Be aware that the Bundle:Template format has pretty much gone away in future versions of Symfony.  You really should go back to using twig namespaces like in your original question.  Something like: "@AhiSpAdmin/Hq ... You can use the command app/console debug:twig to see which twig namespaces you have available.